# Int64 arithmetic error

Tags: c#, largenumber

Why is the output "0 and 0"?  How do I fix it?

```cs
 Int64 small=  (long)0.25 * (long)Int64.MaxValue;
 Int64 large = (long)0.75 * (long)Int64.MaxValue;
 System.Console.WriteLine(small + " and " + large);
 System.Console.ReadLine(); 
 //output 
 //0 and 0
```

Comment: -1 for little effort. This is really easy to solve by trying

Comment: What do you expect this `(long)0.25` to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement `(long)0.75` will return 0  (converting double to long will take greatest integer value, that is lower that converting double). So you have `0 * 9223372036854775807` which is hopefully `0`. By the way `long` is alias for `Int64`, which means they are the **same** underlying types, so by `(long)Int64.MaxValue` you casting `long` to `long`

to fix it simply use `double` * `long` multiplication

```
long small=  (long)(0.25 * long.MaxValue);
long large = (long)(0.75 * long.MaxValue);

Console.WriteLine ("{0:N}", small); //print 2,305,843,009,213,693,952.00
Console.WriteLine ("{0:N}", large); //print 6,917,529,027,641,081,856.00
```

don't bother with `"{0:N}"` literal, it's simply a format to give the output some visual beauty. By default double is printed in scientific notation, which is not so demonstrable (for example `2.30584300921369E+18` for first operation)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that in both cases you are converting a value which is less than 1 to a `long`.  This will truncate the value to `0` hence the multiplication also results in 0

```
Console.WriteLine((long)0.25);  // 0
Console.WriteLine((long)0.75);  // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 0.25 and 0.75 casted as long are 0.

In order to remedy that, you will need to use floats or doubles. However, I'm not 100% certain the precision is enough to lead to exact results:

```
Int64 small=  (Int64)(0.25 * (double)Int64.MaxValue);
Int64 large = (Int64)(0.75 * (double)Int64.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert after not before the multiplication. Try

```
 Int64 small=  (long) (0.25 * (double) Int64.MaxValue);
```

Before you were converting `.25` to `long` which is `0`.